# why Rx.Observer get difference when import from 'rxjs' and 'rx-lite'

Tags: rxjs

Here's the code, and the console output is in comment:

```
import Rx from 'rxjs';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import Rx2 from 'rx-lite';
// import Promise from 'bluebird';
import 'whatwg-fetch';

const componentsData = {};

const availableComponentsObservable = Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
    console.log(Observer); // output: undefined
    console.log(Rx.Observer); // output: undefined
    console.log(Rx2.Observer); // output: function () {}
    fetch('/static/component-list.json').then((res) => res.json())
        .then((components) => { observer.onNext(components); })
        .catch((err) => { observer.onError(err); });
});// .groupBy(component => component.group);

availableComponentsObservable.subscribe((data) => {
    componentsData.availableComponents = data;
});
```

I dont know why when import from `rxjs` got undefined

Comment: Do not mix rx.lite and rxjs, and depending on which one you use you also need to use the correct .js file.

Comment: @Nypan so they are different thing, can have different behavior for same API? ...

Comment: No they are not different per say. But they include different parts of the api, lite includes less. So they will interfere with each other. Take a look at https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS there are som examples och what to include etc and how.

Comment: @Nypan If they has same behavior, then the output of mine code above is wired. while `Observer` imported from `rxjs` is `undefined`, the one imported from `rx-lite` is a `function`. This will cause a problem that `observer.onError` and `observer.onNext` got error: `can't not read onError/onNext of undefined`. These error will be completely striped when using `rx-lite`. And `rxjs`, from what I understand, is the `rx.all.js` said on the rxjs github page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rxjs is https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS the RxJS 5 implementation that Ben Lesh has lead to have a reference implementation of https://github.com/tc39/proposal-observable

It is a rewrite and there are a number of differences in the API. You can find the differences documented here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

rx-lite is part of https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS which is the RxJS 4 implementation.

Note that with modern build tools, and the way you are expected to import each operator/observable you use of RxJS, there is no need for a "lite" version of RxJS 5. Just don't use rx.all.js and use it as documented with build tools that only include the files you use in your final deliverable.